# Reducing from NPC to Co-NPC => NP = Co-NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

In my lecture we learned:

`If X is NPC and X in Co-NP => NP = Co-NP`

Would it be enough to prove `NP = Co-NP` if I reduce a problem just in one direction (from NPC to Co-NPC) in polynomial time?

Or would it be necessary to show this for both directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In short

yes

## Proof

Let's assume $X$ is NP-complete and $X$ is in co-NP.

We show that $NP \subseteq coNP$ and viceversa.

### [$NP\subseteq coNP$]

Because $X$ is NP-complete
$=>$ for each $L\in NP$ we can found a polytime function $f$ that $s\in L$ iff $f(s)\in X$.

But $X$ is in coNP
$=>$ for the *polityme reduction closure* of coNP, $L\in coNP$ too
$=>$ $NP\subseteq coNP$

### [ $coNP \subseteq NP$ ]

let $B\in coNP$
$=>$ $B^c \in NP$
$=>$ $s\in B^c$iff $f(s)\in X$
$=>$ $s\in B$ iff $f(s) \notin X$
$=>$ $s\in B$ iff $f(s) \in X^c$

but because $X \in coNP$
$=> X^c \in NP$ and for *polityme reduction closure* of $NP$
$=> B \in NP$
$=>coNP\subseteq NP$

So $NP=coNP$ under this assumptions.

Comment: So is it right you can assume that X (NPC) is also in co-NP if there exists a reduction to a Co-NP-complete problem?

Comment: yes, if $X$ reduce to $Y$ and $Y\in coNP$ for the *polytime reduction closure* of coNP $X\in coNP$. So this is true even more so if $Y$ is coNP-complete.

Comment: Can you tell me what polytime reduction closure means?

Comment: "We say class X is closed under polynomial reductions
if $(L_1 ≤_p  L_2$ and $L_2\in X)$  $=> L_1\in X$" where $L_1 ≤_p  L_2$ mean that there is a polynomial time reduction from $L_1$  to $L_2$. So it's possible to show that P,NP and coNP (and some other classes) are closed under polynomial reductions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it know.

If I could reduce a NP-complete problem to a coNP-complete problem every problem in NP can be reduced to every coNP-complete problem and it would show that NP is a subset of coNP.

Because every problem A in coNP has a complement co_A in NP

A in coNP => co_A in NP => co_A in coNP => A in NP

=> every Problem in coNP is in NP

=> NP = coNP

If there is a NPC problem that can be reduced to coNPC => NP = coNP

**Edit:** I wrote this while the other answer was given